# Why doesn't this sed command replace the 3rd-to-last "and"?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, gnu

### Update 5/26/2020

It seemed like this was a bug, so I filed a bug. Its ID is #41558.

---

I was just messing around with `sed` and I came up with this exercise: to replace the 3rd-to-last occurrence of "and" (the word, not as a substring), to create:

```
dog XYZ foo and bar and baz land good
```

I thought this would work

```
echo 'dog and foo and bar and baz land good' |
    sed -E 's/(.*)\band\b((.*\band\b){2})/\1XYZ\2/'
```

but it actually replaces the 2nd-to-last occurrence of "and". The only explanation I can think of is that it's including "land" as one of the `\band\b`, but that shouldn't be the case because I included the `\b` word boundaries?

Comment: What's your OS? You might try `[[:<:]]and[[:>:]]` instead of `\band\b`

Comment: That looks very much like a bug. Also in GNU grep: `echo lala | grep -Eo '(\bla){2}'` => `lala`. As a workaround, use `\<` and `\>` instead of `\b`.

Comment: @mosvy the BSD sed on macOS for example doesn't accept either `\b` or the `\<` and `\>` pair

Comment: @Fox I think that the OP is using GNU sed. I've added the [gnu] tag. Let them revert it if it's not true ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, I confirm I'm using GNU sed. Thanks for reminding me to include it!

Comment: Fancy seeing this example, am I right that you're using [my tutorial](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/gnu_sed.md#replace-specific-occurrence)? I converted it into a [book](https://github.com/learnbyexample/learn_gnused) as well.

Comment: I wonder if the bug might be related to this one that I filed: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26864 because here too the expanded version works: `sed -E 's/(.*)\band\b(.*\band\b.*\band\b)/\1XYZ\2/'`

Comment: okay, doesn't seem related to that bug, but with word boundaries, like that grep example provided by @mosvy ... using `\<` and `\>` doesn't help though.. `echo 'the and dog and foo and bar and baz land good' | sed -E 's/(.*)\<and\>((.*\<and\>){1})/\1XYZ\2/'` works but not if you use `{2}` or higher

Comment: and the issue with `\b` seems to be only with words like `land` and `gland` and not `andy` (i.e words ending with `and` but not if there are further characters after `and`)

Comment: @Sundeep, yes indeed! Thanks for the helpful resource :)

Comment: @b0yfriend: Could you add the link to the bug report in your post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is difficult to do as `sed` does not support look-arounds etc. (as you can do in a PCRE).  It would be easier to reverse the string and replace the third occurrence of the reversed word from the start, then reverse again.

```
$ echo 'dog and foo and bar and baz land good' | rev | sed 's/\<dna\>/XXX/3' | rev
dog XXX foo and bar and baz land good
```

---

As for why your expression does not work, this looks like a bug. The back-reference `\3` seem to be the string  `baz land`, as if the `\b` before `and` in `.*\band\b` never had any effect.

The command

```
sed -E 's/(.*)\<and\>((.*\<and\>){2})/\1XYZ\2/'
```

seems to do the right thing on OpenBSD with its native `sed` (which uses `\<` and `\>` instead of `\b`).

I have yet to find an existing bug report against GNU `sed` or GNU `glibc` about this, although I wouldn't be surprised if it was at least *related* to [glibc bug 25322](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25322) (because, see below).

You can work around it by being a bit more verbose:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)\band\b(.*\band\b.*\band\b)/\1XYZ\2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to file an issue. I've tested these examples, which results in same behavior with `GNU grep`, `GNU sed` and `GNU awk`. Except one case, which is noted below.

- Wrong output:

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'cocoa' | sed -nE '/(\bco){2}/p'
  cocoa
  ```

  `sed -nE '/(\<co){2}/p'` and `awk '/(\<co){2}/'` has the buggy behavior too, but `grep -E '(\<co){2}'` correctly doesn't give ouput
- Correct behavior, no output:

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'cocoa' | sed -nE '/\bco\bco/p'
  ```
- Wrong output: there's only 1 whole word `it` after `with`

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'it line with it here sit too' | sed -E 's/with(.*\bit\b){2}/XYZ/'
  it line XYZ too
  ```
- Correct behavior, input isn't modified

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'it line with it here sit too' | sed -E 's/with.*\bit\b.*\bit\b/XYZ/'
  it line with it here sit too
  ```
- Changing word boundaries to `\<` and `\>` results in a different problem.

  This correctly *doesn't modify* the input:

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'it line with it here sit too' | sed -E 's/with(.*\<it\>){2}/XYZ/'
  it line with it here sit too
  ```

  This correctly modifies the input

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'it line with it here it too' | sed -E 's/with(.*\<it\>){2}/XYZ/'
  it line XYZ too
  ```

  But this one fails to modify the input

  ```bsh
  $ echo 'it line with it here it too sit' | sed -E 's/with(.*\<it\>){2}/XYZ/'
  it line with it here it too sit
  ```

Also, the problematic behavior is seen only if the conflicting word has extra characters at the beginning. For example, `it` and `sit`. But not if there are characters at the end. For example, `it` and `site` and `item`.

```bsh
$ echo 'it line with it here item too' | sed -E 's/with(.*\bit\b){2}/XYZ/'
it line with it here item too
$ echo 'it line with it here it too item' | sed -E 's/with(.*\<it\>){2}/XYZ/'
it line XYZ too item
```

Comment: I've filed a bug and mentioned it in the main post, thanks!